# How can I resolve this issue of Virtualkeys.inc

Tags: assembly, irvine32, masm32

When I try to assemble this using masm32, I get a "symbol not defined" error for each line

The error shown is:

[image]

Although Virtualkeys.inc include file is available in the same directory

[image]

I'm using notepad++ with DosBox to compile MASM32 project.

My complete code is:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
INCLUDE Macros.inc

.data
str1 BYTE "Fast Multiplication Program - ** DEMO **",
           0dh,0ah,0dh,0ah,0

.code
main PROC
   call Clrscr
   mov edx,OFFSET str1
   call WriteString

L1:
   mWrite "Enter an unsigned integer (0 to quit): "
   call ReadDec
   .IF CARRY?
      mWrite <"Error: Integer is out of range",0dh,0ah>
      jmp L1
   .ELSE
   mov ebx,eax
   .ENDIF
   cmp eax,0
   je quit


L2:
   mWrite "Enter an unsigned integer: "
   call ReadDec
   .IF CARRY?
      mWrite <"Error: Integer is out of range",0dh,0ah>
      jmp L2
   .ENDIF

   mWrite <"--------------------------------",0dh,0ah>

   ; EBX = multiplicand, EAX = multiplier
   call FastMultiply   ; EAX = product
   jc   L1   ; CF=1 indicates error

   mWrite "The product is:       "
   call WriteDec   ; display product
   call Crlf
   call Crlf
   jmp L1

quit:
   exit
main ENDP
```

Comment: That is a very old version of masm, back in 1987 you had to use [8.3 filenames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename).

Comment: The 80s called, they want their assembler back.  :P  Use something from this century, like JWASM or a recent version of MASM.  Or NASM is good and open-source, but uses different syntax.